# AngularJS ng serve error failed to compile error in node modules/css-loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I didn't encounter this before when developing an angular project. I used angular 2 for this project. Here is the error below when I run the command ng serve in my project dir.

> chunk {chartjs.module} chartjs.module.chunk.js,
>   chartjs.module.chunk.js.map () 13.6 kB {main}  [rendered] chunk
>   {components.module} components.module.chunk.js,
>   components.module.chunk.js.map () 268 kB {main}  [rendered] chunk
>   {dashboard.module} dashboard.module.chunk.js,
>   dashboard.module.chunk.js.map () 64.5 kB {main}  [rendered] chunk
>   {icons.module} icons.module.chunk.js, icons.module.chunk.js.map () 184
>   kB {main}  [rendered] chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js,
>   inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {main}
>   main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 82 kB {vendor} [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {pages.module} pages.module.chunk.js,
>   pages.module.chunk.js.map () 18.5 kB {main}  [rendered] chunk
>   {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills)
>   328 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered] chunk {scripts}
>   scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 358 kB {inline}
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js,
>   styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 10.5 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.53 MB
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {widgets.module} widgets.module.chunk.js,
>   widgets.module.chunk.js.map () 58.5 kB {main}  [rendered]
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/scss/style.scss
>   Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   '/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:952:18)
>       at Object.getInstalledBinaries (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:124:13)
>       at foundBinariesList (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:20:15)
>       at foundBinaries (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:15:5)
>       at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:45:5)
>       at module.exports (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:30)
>       at Object. (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/home/jayzdevera/Documents/ad-fingerprinting/web/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
>   @ ./src/scss/style.scss 4:14-195  @ multi ./src/scss/style.scss
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

My node v is **8.4.0**

Would appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try deleting the `node_modules` directory and reinstall everything

Comment: I tried that already. But it didn't workout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to this problem my self.
The link is below for having the same error with me.
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/226

Just run the **npm install node-sass**

If there is an issue running the npm install node sass then run this command.

**npm install node-sass --no-bin-links**

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try including the built version of chart.js:

"scripts": ["../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"],

or you need to add the path to your .angular-cli.json like this:
    "apps": [

        "scripts": [

            "../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js",

        ],

    ]
```